# Variable is not changing when one button is pressed. (String)

Tags: arduino, programming, button

I couldn't decide whether this belongs in C++ or Arduino. But I guess it belongs here since it's Arduino programming.

Anyways, I'm having a hard time solving this issue. I have 4 buttons, 2 for up/down, 1 for select, and 1 for paging (Switch pages). But the down button is having issues. Here the code:

```cpp
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);

int buttonApin = 6;
int buttonBpin = 5;
int buttonCpin = 4;
int buttonDpin = 3;

int page = 1;

String option1 = "Option A";
String option2 = "Option B";
String option3 = "Option C";
String option4 = "Option D";

String current = "";
String previous = "";

String arrow = "> ";
String selected = arrow + current;

void layoutMenu() {
  lcd.clear();
  String current = option1;
  String selected = arrow + current;
  String previous = option2;

  lcd.print(selected);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(previous);
  while (page == 1) {
    if (digitalRead(buttonApin) == LOW) {
      String current = option1;
      String selected = arrow + current;
      String previous = option2;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);

      lcd.print(selected);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(previous);
    }
    if (digitalRead(buttonBpin) == LOW) {
      String current = option2;
      String selected = arrow + current;
      String previous = option1;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);

      lcd.print(selected);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print(previous);
    }
    if (digitalRead(buttonCpin) == LOW) {
      Serial.print(current); // it was always OptionA when printed to serial.
      if (current == option1) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Selected A");
      }  
      if (current == option2) {
        lcd.clear();
        lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
        lcd.print("Selected B.");
      }
    }
  }
}

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  lcd.print("   Yanny9000   ");
  Serial.begin(9600);
  pinMode(buttonApin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonBpin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonCpin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(buttonDpin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  delay(5000);
  lcd.clear();
  String current = option1;
  String selected = arrow + current;
  String previous = option2;

  lcd.print(selected);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(previous);
  layoutMenu();
}

void loop() {
  // Redesigned the menu. No need for loop().
}
```

Here's the code I'm having problems with:

```cpp
   if (digitalRead(buttonApin) == LOW) {
      String current = option1;
      String selected = arrow + current;
      String previous = option2;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);

      lcd.print(selected);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(previous);
    }
    if (digitalRead(buttonBpin) == LOW) {
      String current = option2;
      String selected = arrow + current;
      String previous = option1;
      lcd.clear();
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);

      lcd.print(selected);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print(previous);
    }
```

A is up, B is down. When the up button is pressed, it selects an option named "Option A" and changes the vars: Current (Which contains the current option selected), Selected (Displays option selected), and Previous (Previous Option).

When B is pressed, it selected an option named "Option B" and changes Selected and Previous.

**Issue: Current does not change when B is pressed.**

Current is used by C button (Select) to select options. For some odd reason it does not change. I been trying to solve this problem for ages. Can anyone help me? I'm using an mega 2560.

Comment: you have up, down, select, page buttons .... why would you name them A, B, C, D ? .... that kind of thinking is couterproductive

Comment: It was the first thing to come to mind, didn't think of naming them.. "SelectBtn" or "PageBtn" at the moment. So, I just named them A, B, C, and D. @jsotola

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not Arduino but basic C++ question.

You are creating a new local string variable with the same name than your global variable, and changing the local variable. The global variable will not change.

Comment: I now realized where I gone wrong, I've declared 'current'  two times in this statement, I removed "String" and now it works. This was a beginner's mistake, I'm new to C++. I also couldn't tell whether this was Arduino or C++. I don't know much about Arduino and .ino files. I guessed Arduino because of .ino at the end of every Arduino file. Anyways, thanks for answering!

Comment: Arduino is not a programming language. Arduino is a hardware platform with framework and libraries written in C++.